# Why does heavy disk access cause input hitching/lag in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In the past year, all of my computers have started having a behavior where heavy disk/cpu usage will block or cause input lag. The mouse will hitch, keyboard input will be super slow as if it's throttled. I have never seen this behavior before outside of very old PC issues where hard drives were running in PIO mode.

It happens on all four of the machines I have access to. Two of them have SSDs as primary hard disks. One of them, a laptop, is running a completely new and fresh install. None of them have any viruses.

This seems to be a new thing, as none of these machines behaved this way until fairly recently (the oldest machine is 5 years old, the newest is only 2.5 years old). There's no commonality in any of the hardware. (Macbook pro, core i7 920 system, core i5-2500 system, and a dell laptop with an older i5).

My best guess at this point is some kind of change in windows itself with regards to input event handling, but that seems crazy to me.

Comment: How old are the SSDs?  Have you updated the firmware on all the SSDs?

Comment: one year and five years. But since the issue happens on machines without SSDs, I doubt they are the root cause.